# Create a dynamic page clicking on a row from a dynamically created table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to open a new page, whenever i click a row in my table.
This table was generated getting data from a database. I need whenever i click a X row from the table you get redirected to a page with detailed info of this row. 
I have no idea how to redirect to a non-static webpage depending on which row i clicked, also... i need help to know which row was clicked so i know which data i should get from the database again(to show in this new page). The only thing i've tried before was redirecting using the ref tag, but in this case wont work.

My plan so far:

```
            <tr class ="fila" id=<? echo $row["id"] ; ?>>
            <td ><? echo $row["nombre_disfraz"]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $nombreregion; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $nombrecomuna; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $nombrecategoria ?></td>
            <td><? echo $nombretalla; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $row["nombre_contacto"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Thats how i generate my table right now, each id is unique for each row... my plan is to do a javascript for the class "fila", and somehow pass the variable id from the javascript using something like this.id to php, so i can have a single webpage called details.php and i can ask for the data to database again because i have an id... is this a good plan?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to Ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan is good, and follows a very standard pattern. It's not clear exactly what stopped you from researching and attempting it, but here's the finished article anyway:

Set a "click" event listener on all elements with the "fila" class. Then inside the handler, get the ID of the clicked element, and use JavaScript to navigate to the new page, using the ID as a querystring parameter.

Demo:

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.fila');
rows.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var url = "details.php?id=" + this.id;
    console.log(url);
    window.location = url;
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fila:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="fila" id="1">
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      23r
    </td>
    <td>
      fgdfg
    </td>
    <td>
      g4gfg
    </td>
    <td>
      4gw3g>
    </td>
    <td>
      23rgdfgd
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila" id="2">
    <td>
      2
    </td>
    <td>
      x
    </td>
    <td>
      y
    </td>
    <td>
      z
    </td>
    <td>
      a
    </td>
    <td>
      b
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila" id="300">
    <td>
      300
    </td>
    <td>
      x
    </td>
    <td>
      y
    </td>
    <td>
      z
    </td>
    <td>
      c
    </td>
    <td>
      d
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```